# Basic Xamarin Android SDK Issue

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-sdk-tools

I've never struggled with anything in programming as much as this Xamarin installation, unbelievably flakey. I've got my environment (VS 2015 Enterprise) to a point whereby I can spin up a new Blank App (Android) but the designer requires a newer version of the Android SDK (apparently):

[image]

I've only *just* installed the latest Android Studio, so I can confirm (in Xamarin settings) I'm pointing to the correct path for the SDK (in AppData/Local etc.)

On opening the SDK manager I can see the latest SDK tools is installed.

Please note: I've also tried running the SDK manager independently of VS (and as admin).

Never had this much trouble trying to get something installed and configured. Any help MASSIVELY appreciated.

Whoever helps me crack this gets a massive bounty.

EDIT:

Found this in the logs, fairly certain this is the issue:

**Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane Error: 0 : [2016-09-22 16:36:54.2716] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.Designer.MonoAndroidDesignerDocumentCache.Push(String filePath, AndroidDesignerDocumentCacheItem value) in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerDocumentCache.cs:line 25
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.OpenViewCode() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 619
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerPane.b__66_0() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerPane.cs:line 612**

EDIT

Bounty is for Jon when it allows me to award it. This issue has already been resolved.

Comment: What is your java version?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you run Visual Studio in administrator mode?

Comment: @GBoehm - yes, I always run as admin (I've tried without too though). Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Milen - 'Java Development Kit 7 Update 55' on my machine is version 1.7.0.550

Comment: You'll need java 1.8 for android 7

Comment: @milen this or the path to jdk/environment var is not correctly set would be my next guess

Comment: Problem after problem after problem: http://oi65.tinypic.com/2jcucr9.jpg Checked the logs, just says 'internal server error'

Comment: what emulator are you are using?

Comment: @MarcosJoséPérezPérez Not sure how I can tell. I haven't got as far as that yet, to be honest. This is just the 'Designer' view.

Comment: Can you post an archive of your logs? Log files can be gathered from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Log` Or you can use the `Help->Xamarin->Zip Logs(7 days)`. My best guess here is that you have an old Android SDK reference in your project. Please also post a diagnostic build output: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx (VS)

Comment: I didn't know about these logs @JonDouglas - thanks very much for your reply. I'll work on getting them posted up in a min, one thing I have noticed was this though: `Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-22 16:37:12.3142] No license found for Android
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-22 16:37:12.3331] Running license sync for Android
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-09-22 16:37:12.3535] Not logged in, using Android VSEnterprise` Not sure if that is of any relevance?

Comment: Further to all of this, my issues with installing has been resolved (it was a system-wide issue since Windows\Installer was missing). So I've bumped Java up to the latest version, downloaded the latest NDK, and ensured the SDK is upto date via the manager. This is a headache.

Comment: Just upload the Zip or put a link to a dropbox/etc and I'll look through them. The build output will most likely have more information about what's going on here. Please post both of these items to your question.

Comment: @JonDouglas - thanks very much for your reply. I don't believe there are build issues, it's building fine. Or am I misunderstanding the purpose of the build output? Thanks again Jon, any help on this much appreciated.

Comment: Logs are added to the question @JonDouglas

Comment: The reason why I ask for build output is that it will tell us exactly what tooling is being used in your project. So a diagnostic build output will help here as well.

Comment: @JonDouglas - that's fair, give me a sec and I'll save it...

Comment: @JonDouglas - build log uploaded. You may find some little bits missing (only to do with the logon server or my username (so paths may appear Users\\\\ where I've removed my username)). Again, thanks mate, appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete your `obj/bin` folders as it seems you might have an `AndroidSdksCache` holding the old version. Specifically look for a file here `obj\Debug\sdks.cache`.

The second note is that you have `build-tools` 23.0.0 installed. Please uninstall that version and any other old version and install `24.0.2`.

It shows the current directory as being `C:\sdk1\` when the referenced SDK version is different in your screenshot. You will need to update `C:\sdk1\` to the latest Android SDK Tools.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Jon. Just deleted obj/bin folders but unfortunately still the same problem (can't load the designer). I don't believe I had 23.0.0 installed according to the SDK manager. Regardless, I've uninstalled all build-tools apart from the latest (25.2.2) and have installed 24.0.2 as instructed. No immediate change, so I restarted VS - still won't load designer and is asking for 25.1.3 or later. Apologies for not explaining the change in SDK directory - since Marcos' answer I eliminated any issues with the path by moving it to the root instead.

Comment: It is interesting that you said 23.0.0 is installed. Is that from the build log you've seen that? It could be that VS thinks 23.0.0 is all I have for some reason (which would explain the error message) whereas the SDK Manager is aware of the updates I've made.

Comment: `AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion: 23.0.0 ` I see it now. Hmmm. I wonder why it thinks I'm on 23.0.0

Comment: Make sure you are updating both SDKs as one is being cached as per your logs, and the other is being used in your Xamarin Settings. I would recommend deleting one of the fully so there's no doubt which one you're using. Your build logs showed what I concluded. Then open the SDK manager with the proper path.

Comment: Deleted the original SDK, now I have just this new C:\sdk1. Still the same problem. I noticed in the build log it points to sdk1\build-tools\24.0.1, there doesn't seem to be a 25 etc. there!?

Comment: Scratch that, I didn't notice version 25... wasn't build-tools but was just 'tools'. My bad.

Comment: Still non-the-wiser here. I'm open to ideas of any big 'overkill' type approaches now.

Comment: Start fresh: Uninstall your JDKs, Android SDKs, Xamarin. Reinstall each one accordingly: 1) JDK 1.8 2) Android SDK Update to 25.2.2 3) Latest Stable version of Xamarin. At this point it's too hard to follow what is going on with your machine.

Comment: The sledgehammer approach of removing everything and installing VS 2015 done the job. Thank you very much Jon, I appreciate you taking the time out to help a stranger mate, nice one.

Comment: Glad that worked. When in doubt, start from square 1!

Comment: Awarded a bounty Jon, you went above and beyond trying to help me mate, checking logs n all that. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be many things.

1) some time your user name in your PC if have character specials like accents or spaces. Make problems with the VS.

2) you need check if you install Visual studio Emulator android. After donwload a device and check the api that have that device.

Windows 8 or windows 10 pro.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx

Don´t use the generic emulator. If you dont know how configure.

3)Make sure that you have install Xamarin correctly in your VS.

Tool -> options -> Xamarin

you need watch all the green check.
[image: xamarin]

if the android dont have the green check. Search the route when you have install the sdk. For example watch the image. My root for example

Let me know if this solve your problem. Regards.

Comment: I can't install that emulator, another internal error. I don't think that's the answer anyway, and my Xamarin settings look fine.

Comment: I think that your error is related with with your user name in your pc. Show me what is your username. go to C:\Users\[ your user name ]

Comment: It has a dot in it. Either way, I've moved the sdk to C:\ and referenced that, still no joy.

Comment: because the problem affect Visual Studio not only the sdk. Solution to your  problem. Change the name and modify the register change all the names of the old user for the new, or create a new user and install all VS2015 again. If hard but I have the same crazy errors. and I solved in this form.